# Tracking the progress of a ProgressMessageBox: GXT 3.0.1

Tags: gxt

I created a progressmessagebox which tracks the progress when my client is loading. I want to be able to update the user on what is going on in real time, specifically I have these 3 "subgoals":

1-"Initializing..." : %0 complete

2-"Retrieving lab configuration..." : %30 complete

3-"Starting the client..." : %80 complete

4-"Client is ready" :%100

This is a skeleton of the code I currently have, it doesn't work though, it does not display steps 2 and 3:

```
final ProgressMessageBox box = new ProgressMessageBox("Please wait", "Loading items...");
    box.setProgressText("Initializing...");
    box.show();


    final Timer t = new Timer() {
      float i;

      @Override
      public void run() {
        box.updateProgress(i / 100,  "{0}% Complete");
        i += 5;
        if (i > 100) {
          cancel();
          Info.display("Message", "Client is ready");
        }
      }
    };
    t.scheduleRepeating(500);

box.updateProgress(0.3, "Retrieving lab configuration...");
//code to retrieve the lab configuration..

box.updateProgress(0.8, "Starting the client...");
//code to start the client...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to use multhithreading in order to avoid form freezing.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057999/how-to-make-a-loader-in-a-separate-thread) : How to make a loader in a separate thread?

Comment: This answer doesn't appear to have any relevance to GXT.